# Configure apache to listen on port other than 80

Tags: apache2, apache-config

I use centOS server.  I want to configure apache to listen on port 8079.
I added LISTEN 8079 directive in `httpd.conf`.
I opened port 8079 in iptables and restarted iptables. I even stopped iptables service.

```
"netstat -nal | grep 8079" shows "tcp  0 0 :::8079 :::* LISTEN"
```

If I try to access `http://localhost:8079` or `http://myserver.com:8079` from that machine, I can access that page.  BUT from any other machine I am not able to access the site on any port other than 80. On port 80, it works. On port 8079 it does not.

What else do I need to configure?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It was a firewall issue. There was a hardware firewall that was blocking access to almost all ports. (Turning off software firewall / SELinux bla bla had no effect)

Then I scanned the open ports and used the port that was open.

If you are facing the same problem, Run the following command

```
sudo nmap -T Aggressive -A -v 127.0.0.1 -p 1-65000
```

It will scan for all the open ports on your system. Any port that is open can be accessed from outside.

**Ref**.: http://www.go2linux.org/which_service_or_program_is_listening_on_port

Comment: netstat -anp | grep apache2

(You could see the listening port and PID from this if it's running.Ubuntu)

Comment: My cloud service provider had a firewall on top that was blocking the port. Check firewalls placed other than in the target server.

Answer (score 169):

In `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, change the port as

```
Listen 8079
```

Then go to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

And change the first line as

```
<VirtualHost *: 8079>
```

Now restart

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Apache will now listen on port 8079 and redirect to /var/www/html

Comment: No, just the "This webpage is not available" annoying message.
Just to clarify, port 80 works perfectly. Changing both the VirtualHost and the Listen doesn't solve it for me. (AWS ubuntu).

B.T.W the reason I need it to listen to a different port is because I've also configured nginx to listen to 80.

Comment: quick question: did you open up the inbound port in the security groups as you say you're on AWS ubuntu ?

Comment: if there is line `NameVirtualHost *:80` above `Listen 80` do change that as well ......

Answer (score 82):

Open httpd.conf file in your text editor. 
Find this line:

```
Listen 80
```

and change it

```
Listen 8079
```

After change, save it and restart apache.

Comment: yes, but I mentioned in the first line that I have already tried this "I added LISTEN 8079 directive in httpd.conf" :((

Comment: Oh sory. I didnt see it. Can you post httpd.conf file any where? And are you using 3rd party software Wamp,Xampp,Appserv?

Comment: you can get httpd.conf here http://www.fileuploading.net/860467
nothing like WAMP, Xampp, Appserv. All I have done is compiling apache, tomcat and jk connector from source and trying my best to make them work together.

Comment: i didnt find the problem :( everything seems normally. i tried add Listen 8076 line in my local server but its worked normally. Can you try re-setup apache if is possible?

Comment: as I said, on localhost it's working on my pc also. anyway, thanks for your answer. i only want  to setup communication between apache and tomcat and for that probably apache runnning on port 80 is enough. i am still learning about it.

Comment: ismailperim, yeah I use xampp. But its not started as of now. There is no IIS installed too, and no service listening on port 80. Any suggestions ? I also uninstalled and reinstalled Apache.

Edit : Got it. I had modified my httpd.conf file to configure SVN server.(step 7 os this manual: http://willperone.net/Code/svnserver.php)

Comment: where is the httpd.conf file located? in my /etc/apache2 folder there is a apache2.conf file - is this the same as the httpd file? Because there are many such configuration files in this folder. any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: One thing everybody seems to forget when answering this kind of questions is to mention the file location. The file is located in /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Comment: @ismailperim I can able to change the port number from 80 to 8070 by changing as you said, and it is able to run on the 8070 port. But after few days the port number gets changed to 80 automatically. How do I stop it?

Answer (score 22):

If you need apache Listen port other than 80, you should add next file under ubuntu

> "/etc/apache2/ports.conf"

the list of Listen ports

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
Listen 82
```

After you have to go on your Virtual hosts conf file and define next

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  #...v host 1
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:81>
  #...host 2
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:82>
  #...host 3
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 10):

This is working for me on Centos

**First:** in file **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

add

```
Listen 8079
```

after

```
Listen 80
```

This till your server to listen to the port 8079

**Second:** go to your virtual host for ex. **/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf**

and add this code below

```
<VirtualHost *:8079>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api_folder
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   ServerAdmin root@example.com
   ErrorLog logs/www.example.com-error_log
   CustomLog logs/www.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

This mean when you go to your `www.example.com:8079` redirect to

**/var/www/html/api_folder**

But you need first to restart the service

`sudo service httpd restart`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [Apache on Windows](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html):

1. Check the name of the Apache service with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+`services.msc`+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (if it's not ApacheX.Y, it should have the name of the software you are using with apache, e.g.: "wampapache64");
2. Start a [command prompt as **Administrator**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+`cmd`+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is not enough);
3. Change to Apache's directory, e.g.: `cd c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`;
4. Check if the config file is OK with: `httpd.exe -n "YourServiceName" -t` (replace the service name by the one you found on step 1);
5. Make sure that the service is stopped: `httpd.exe -k stop -n "YourServiceName"`
6. Start it with: `httpd.exe -k start -n "YourServiceName"`
7. If it starts alright, the problem is no longer there, but if you get:

   > AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address IP:PORT_NUMBER
   >
   > AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down

   If the port number is not the one you wanted to use, then open the Apache config file (e.g. `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf` open with a code editor or wordpad, but **not notepad** - it does not read new lines properly) and replace the number on the line that starts with `Listen` with the number of the port you want, save it and repeat step 6. If it is the one you wanted to use, then continue:
8. Check the PID of the process that is using that port with  <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+`resmon`+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, click on **Network** tab and then on **Ports** subtab;
9. Kill it with: `taskkill /pid NUMBER /f` (`/f` forces it);
10. Recheck `resmon` to confirm that the port is free now and repeat step 6.

This ensures that Apache's service was started properly, the configuration on [virtual hosts config file as sarul mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064554/1326147) (e.g.: `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`) is necessary if you are setting your files path in there and changing the port as well. If you change it again, remember to restart the service: `httpd.exe -k restart -n "YourServiceName"`.

Answer (score 1):

For FC22 server

cd /etc/httpd/conf
edit httpd.conf [enter]

Change:
Listen 80
to:
Listen whatevernumber

Save the file

systemctl restart httpd.service [enter]
if required, open whatevernumber in your router / firewall

Answer (score 1):

Run this command if your ufw(Uncomplicatd Firewall) is enabled .
Add for Example port 8080

```
$ sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp
```

And you can check the status by running

```
$ sudo ufw status
```

For more info check :
https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_allow_port_firewall