# Xampp; Apache Port 80 Busy

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I am having Port Problem.

Whenever I start Apache then it give me this error:

> Busy - Apache Started [port 80]

And When i start Mysql then Folowing Error Appears:

> Busy - ERROR: Mysql service not started [-1]

Please Anyone tell me that how to resolve this problem.

Waiting for Replies.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What platform you are using? Windows or Linux? If windows, run services.msc to check for any conflicting services that may block the port 80 for apache. Usually it would be IIS.

Comment: Well I am using Windows 7..
And I did not see IIS in the list.
Please guide me. I searched a lot from here. But i did not get help.

Answer (score 1):

Open `cports.exe` (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html), find in the column `Local Port` the port 80. Thus, you will know which program uses this port and you will be able to kill it.

Answer (score 1):

For most people, port 80 is occupied by Skype by default. Simply uninstall Skype and port 80 will be freed. Apache should then work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this below command in cmd prompt

`netstat -ano|find "port no"`

Eg:

`netstat -ano|find "3306"`

> TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5164
>
> TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING       5164

You could even use the pid number and check in windows task manager who is utilizing these pid so that you would come to know the exact process name

Please provide error log file if possible.

Major issue comes if you are using skype . Just change the connection port no and restart skype and try to start apache

Answer (score -1):

You should search then you ask question because this question has been asked. You need to go to C:\xampp\apache\conf edit httpd.conf file and change

Listen 80

to

Listen 8081 
or another number then you restart apache.

other links
[Configure apache to listen on port other than 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80)

Comment: Well, I Searched a lot but i did not find solution for my issue.
thats why i posted here. 

I also changed from Listen 80 to 8081 but its still do not work.
So please help me.

Comment: what version of apache have you installed?

Comment: ApacheFriends XAMPP (Basispaket) version 1.7.4 
 + Apache 2.2.17
  + MySQL 5.5.8 (Community Server)
  + PHP 5.3.5 (VC6 X86 32bit) + PEAR

Comment: restart your computer if i doesn't work reinstall xampp and change port again i had the same problem a week ago i had 1.8.1 then installed 1.7.4 changed the port and all was fine hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Edit the httpd file

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

to something like this

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8080
```

Just make sure you use any port other than 80.

Check if any instances of mysqld.exe is running from task manager. If so kill it and start it from xampp control panel.

Answer (score -1):

If you have skype running on your local computer it uses port 80 also. So port 80 can not allocate for MySQL. The solution is  to stop running on skype and then start your xampp server. If it is also not working just try to uninstall skype and then again install your xampp server. This time probably can run MySQL.