# routing 2 sepparet machines on the same IP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, hosting

I have a shop with 2 computers and an online security camera system connected to a router.

I want to be able to host a "website" from one of the computers but it looks like the security camera is using the default port for my IP address.

The website is hosted on the computer using xampp.

What I did so far is as following:

1. Made sure the router remembers the computer by MAC address and gives it the same IP address all the time.
2. Forwarded that ip address of the computer to port 5000 ( didnt work ) and tried also 21 ( also didnt work)
3. I made sure the windows firewall allows port 21 and 5000.
4. Deleted the following line from XAMPP configuration file "httpd-xampp.conf"

```html
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
 ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Still not working... 
I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. maybe 1 router cant host more then 1 website or I don't know.. 
Would very much appreciate help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forward the request to another port, you must configure apache to listen to this other port as well. If not apache will listen to port 80 by default. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80)