# Apache Change Default User

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I wish to run apache under a user named app_user. To achieve this I changed the following in the httpd.conf file

```
User app_user
Group app_user
```

app_user is a valid user and a group on this server.

The app_user has correct privileges to write in /var/log/httpd directory.

Now when i start apache it gives me this error.

```
[app_user@localhost conf]$ service httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 'root' user can bind connections to ports lesser than 1024. For more information [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user). Either configure the apache to use [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80) port number which is higher than 1024 or [sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42066/how-to-assign-user-root-rights) as root user. Later option is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Root should start apache main process to bind lower ports but, if you want to use different user/group for the sub processes you can configure through **APACHE_RUN_USER** and **APACHE_RUN_GROUP** environmental variables.
check  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
 User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
 Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```