# apache2 not responding in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I was having some problems with apache2 in Ubuntu and decided to uninstall and reinstall it. The problem now is that when I try

```
which apache2
```

or even

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

I get absolutely no response. I tried inspecting element of one of my PHP scripts and `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` shows up in the log. The one command that seems to work is

`whereis apache2`

which returns apache2: /etc/apache2 /usr/share/apache2

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You need to include at least what OS/distro you are using as a tag so someone who knows that disto can offer some help.

Comment: Sorry about that, added the changes

Comment: If this is a case of a server your server maybe compromised and might contain rootkits. I had a simillar situation with rsync not showing up with the which command. Solution is recover your important files and spin-up a new server

Comment: Sorry to ask but how would I go about recovering my important files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you tried the following (with the following order too)?

First Uninstall Apache

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then, install it as normal...

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Then goto to a terminal and check (as i did in my terminal) :

```
andreas@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ps -ALL |grep apache2
1564  1564 ?        00:00:00 apache2
...
```

Finally check from your browser:

```
http://localhost
```

Comment: Ok I tried going through the commands again and followed your steps but `ps -ALL |grep apache2` and localhost don't respond

Comment: Did you tried to `sudo apt-get update` and then restart?

Comment: yea, still no response

Comment: I am affraid that you have still files on your system from old apache2 installation. Do you know how to setup apache in different port (say 8080) than the default (80)?

Comment: I found this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80) but I don't have httpd.conf. I checked apache2.conf and `listen 80` isn't there either. Would it be somewhere else?

Comment: In apache2 there is some slight different approach. Please read the comments in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and you will see that there is a  file in the same dir, called `ports.conf` that will contains all the ports definition. If this is not your case then your `/etc/apache2/` may be corupted. I suggest to remove it and try to re-install apache2... again!!

Comment: Sorry about that I just found it.  And changed the port. I tried restarting after with `sudo service apache2 restart` but still no response....

Comment: first try this command to load apache `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload`. If still fails then try following this steps: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/troubleshooting-apache-webserver-will-not-restart-start/

Comment: I'm having some problems trying to ssh into the server. I also found this `The program 'apache2' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install apache2-bin` and when I install apache2-bin I still get the error...Is there some way to completely wipe everything and install from the ground up?

Comment: Yes, try this:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/176964/permanently-removing-apache2

Comment: Thanks! I got my server up now!....sort of a side question if you don't mind but is there a reason my php files are being printed in browser instead of running it?

Comment: OK... I am glad it works.
Now you have to make your `apache` to understand php. Your last problem is relatively easy to be solved... Just check here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing