# iptables, apache, Linux Mint (Ubuntu), forward from port 80 to 1080, no listening sockets available, shutting down

Tags: linux, apache, iptables

I have rewritten the question, using the answer from Pedro.

I am getting the error  `“no listening sockets available, shutting down”`, when i try to execute simple script :

```
$  apache2ctl -f `pwd`/conf/httpd.conf -d `pwd`
```

on Linux Mint based on Ubuntu.

i am in the directory  `/usr/www/apache3/site.toddle`,
The contents of `/usr/www/apache3/site.toddle/conf/httpd.conf` is

```
User www-data
Group www-data
# added to get rid of apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load
Include /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf

#copied from 000-default.conf from /etc/apache2/sites-available
<VirtualHost *:1081>
    ServerName my586
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/www/apache3/site.toddle/htdocs/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have followed the Pedro answer and links.

1) using `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/ports.conf` added to the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` the line and saved the file:

```
#original: Listen 80
Listen 1081
```

2) restarted apache using `$ sudo  /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

3) configured iptables using Pedro example for port 1081:

```
 sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1081
 sudo iptables-save
 sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1081
 sudo iptables-save
```

But running the command: `apache2ctl -f`pwd`/conf/httpd.conf -d`pwd
gives the error `"no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action '-f /usr/www/apache3/site.toddle/conf/httpd.conf -d /usr/www/apache3/site.toddle' failed."`

Checking with netstat, gives that apache listens to the port 1081:

```
$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':1081'
tcp6       0      0 :::1081        :::*   LISTEN      3160/apache2
```

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but have you tried something like `sudo service apache2 restart`? You might be trying to start it without stopping it first.

Answer (score 1):

The rules that have always worked for me for redirecting incoming traffic on port 80 to an apache server on port 1080 are:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1080
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1080
```

You could test these rules by listening with netcat on port 1080 on your server, and trying to connect to your server on port 80 using netcat from a different machine.

Then make sure that your apache server has it's config set to you port 1080.

See this post for setting Apache to run on different port:
[Configure apache to listen on port other than 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80)

Comment: thank you so much. Seems my error is somewhere else. If i do like you said, i am getting the error : `(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:1080
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:1080
no listening sockets available, shutting down.` Seems the reason is that my script envoke /usr/www/apache3/site.toddle/conf/httpd.conf, which is is not able to connect 1080,  because /etc/apache2/ports.conf also listen to this port.

Comment: I deleted `listen 1081` from  `/usr/www/apache3/site.toddle/conf/httpd.conf`, leaving `listen 1081` only in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` . I have followed your (Pedro) instructions/commands. In the end, if i checked `$ sudo netstat -ltnl | grep ':1081' `  ---->  i am getting :  `tcp6       0      0 :::1081                 :::*                    LISTEN`  , which does not give apache2 as listening program. How to understand this output? Anyway my script is still not working and i am getting the error : `no listening sockets available, shutting down`.

Comment: Do you have apache3 and apache2 running? If so, try stopping one of them as they may be fighting over ports. Try the -p option to make netstat show the program. Your grep'd output suggests you're only listening on 1081 using ipv6.

Comment: i run apache2. The apache3 in folder name comes from the first example `site.toddle` of Apache 3rd ed.. Laurie, Ben. ;Laurie, Peter. ;2007

Comment: I have rewritten the question based on your example. I am still getting the error `no listening sockets available, shutting down`