# Serve Laravel on a custom port number

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan

I am using **laravel 5.3** and this may be a basic question but I want know how I can serve Laravel on a custom port number *(port 1000)*.

Comment: What is your OS ?

Comment: This post will help you, [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For port 1000:

```
php artisan serve --port=1000
```

Comment: Hossain-Thanks it working

Comment: @Shanukk If it works. mark as accepted :)

Comment: Hossain -when i click on tick mark get an error like 'you can accept an answer in 4 minuts'