# XAMPP - "Bad Request" When I try to access https port

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Im trying to change the ports that XAMPP listen on in the https port. I am modifying the httpd-ssl.conf file. I have changed the

```
Listen 443 to Listen 8483
```

I also changed the

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443> to <VirtualHost _default_:8483>
```

and

```
ServerName www.example.com:443 to localhost:8483
```

but when I try to access the localhost:8483 I am getting a bad request

[image]

Comment: did you restart the server? XAMPP in your case

Comment: Yes I restart XAMPP everytime I make any changes to the config files

Comment: wait, doesnt XAMPP have a GUI interface to change the ports? have you tried that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Comment: There may also be a ports.conf file. I'm running true LAMP on linux, and it's at /etc/apache2/ports.conf . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80

Comment: Yea true LAMP is the way to go. I use Docker for all my apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) change in "httpd.conf"

Listen 8483

ServerName localhost:8483

2) change in "httpd-ssl.conf"

Listen 8483

VirtualHost *default*:8483

ServerName localhost:8483

3)Restart the Apache Server.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, but I just ran into it again...

Make sure you put "https://" into your browser's address bar. If you use port 443, then the browser automatically assumes https, if you use any other port, it doesn't. So if you just enter

localhost:8483

into your address bar, the browser uses HTTP to access an HTTPS port - so you get a "bad request". Make sure you use

https://localhost:8483/

in your address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You must restart the apache service.

Comment: well he said he restarted xampp, maybe he just turned off/on xampp gui

Comment: this is true. Good eye.