# Apache2 on Valet

Tags: laravel, apache, nginx, laravel-valet

Is there any way I can use `apache2` on `Laravel Valet` ? I need to write some code to the `.htaccess` file. The site on our server uses apache but I am running Valet which uses `nginx`, so I cannot test it before putting it to the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.

> ## [Installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet#installation)
>
> Valet requires macOS and Homebrew. Before installation, you should
> make sure that no other programs such as Apache or Nginx are binding
> to your local machine's port 80.

You [could install apache and configure it to run on a different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80), but you will lose the benefits of Valet.

Comment: Sure. I will lose the benefits of the valet. But I can run both: the Valet linked sites using nginx and also apache sites where I will have to access via vhosts or localhost?

Comment: yep, this is possible. but I'm curious: what do you want to write into the .htaccess file? often there is a way to port that over to nginx

Comment: Because the site is on the server that runs on apache server,  on the other hand my local machine runs nginx and I do not want to edit it directly on the sharp server so I cannot try the code before pulling from sharp

Comment: @Epsilon47 Why do you lose the benefit?