# CentOS 7 httpd non standart port

Tags: http, centos7, httpd.conf

I'm wondering why I can't run httpd service when I edit `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file with fallowing value:

`Listen 8811`

Service runs smoothly with fallowing ports:

`Listen 80`

`Listen 8080`

As soon as I change it to 8811, service won't start.

Any idea, why is this happening? And how can I set it desired port?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80 not sure if you've already looked here

Answer (score 0):

Disabling firewall did the trick:

`# setenforce 0`