# Dokku: Nginx fails, address already in use

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, dokku

I am attempting to install Dokku on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 instance hosted on AWS. Connection is via ssh. The installation script repeatedly fails due to an Nginx error. I am not familiar with Nginx so I can't interpret what the issue is. I initially tried to install on Ubuntu 14. I had the same error there. The Dokku documentation suggested that there may be issues with the apt repository on Ubuntu 14. I followed the steps to update the apt repository with a newer Nginx, but this did not work. So I moved to an Ubuntu 16.04 instance. However, I still have this problem. What is the issue and how do I resolve it? Thanks.

Nginx version:

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

Commands as per Dokku:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dokku/dokku/v0.12.12/bootstrap.sh
```

(no issues)

```
sudo DOKKU_TAG=v0.12.12 bash bootstrap.sh
```

(causes error below)

Error log below:

```
Setting up nginx-core (1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-08-16 13:45:02 UTC; 5ms ago
  Process: 23440 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 23436 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 16 13:45:01 nginx[23440]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 16 13:45:01 nginx[23440]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 16 13:45:01 nginx[23440]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 16 13:45:02 nginx[23440]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 16 13:45:02 nginx[23440]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to [::]:80, backlog 511 failed (98: Address already in use)
Aug 16 13:45:02  nginx[23440]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Aug 16 13:45:02  systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 16 13:45:02  systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Aug 16 13:45:02 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 16 13:45:02 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) | nginx-full (>= 1    .10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) |     nginx-extras (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
   Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
   Package nginx-full is not installed.
   Package nginx-light is not installed.
   Package nginx-extras is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Setting up cgroupfs-mount (1.2) ...
 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                               Setting up plugn (0.3.0) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
 Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
 Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Some apache server was listening on port 80. This answer shows how to change that.

[Configure apache to listen on port other than 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80)