# How to run Apache on AWS EC2 Cloud9

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

I migrated from Cloud9 to AWS Cloud9. I'm unable to see the preview of the Apache server. The server is running :

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-83:~/environment$ sudo service apache2 status
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-04-11 09:17:31 UTC; 17min ago
  Process: 791 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 997 (apache2)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─ 997 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1086 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1087 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1088 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1089 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─1090 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Apr 11 09:17:29 ip-172-31-22-83 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 11 09:17:31 ip-172-31-22-83 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

But when I try previewing the server, nothing works:

- localhost/

> Client Closed Request 499 - AWSCloud9VFSService VFS connection does
>   not exist

- localhost:8080

> Cannot GET /vfs/80990xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/previewlocalhost:8080

I already tryed this :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-app-reload

But it's a fake server and don't load the root file `index.php`. It displays list of files in folders and do not consider .htaccess files.

I also try changing port for 8080 according to [Configure apache to listen on port other than 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80)

Answer (score 0):

Apache is natively running on AWS Cloud9. To make Apache working with the Cloud9 IDE preview system, you need to :

- [Make Apache running on port 8080, 8081 or 8082.](https://www.lucidar.me/en/web-dev/how-to-run-apache-on-aws-ec2-cloud9-server/#configure-apache-on-port-8080)
- [Configure Apache Root directory to ~/environment](https://www.lucidar.me/en/web-dev/how-to-run-apache-on-aws-ec2-cloud9-server/#set-apache-root-directory)
- [Enable .htaccess](https://www.lucidar.me/en/web-dev/how-to-run-apache-on-aws-ec2-cloud9-server/#configure-htaccess)

A step-by-step guide is detailed on [this page](https://www.lucidar.me/en/web-dev/how-to-run-apache-on-aws-ec2-cloud9-server/)